# Mac shell script with date in backup file

Tags: macos, shell

I've create a shell script that needs to take a postgresql backup. And to delete the files who are older then 4days. But when I run this script. It creates: "backup_db_01_06_2012  *  *" and if i append the .backup to it, the backup file doesn't work correctly. Can you guys help me? You can find the script below.

```
CUR_DATE=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")
BACKUP_FILE="/folder/backup/backup_db_$CUR_DATE"

find /folder/backup -name "*.backup" -type f -Btime +4d -delete

/Applications/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_dump \
    -h localhost -p 5432 \
    -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "$BACKUP_FILE" db
```

Comment: You're saying the filename created is literally `"backup_db_01_06_2012 * *"` with spaces and stars not included in your definition  `BACKUP_FILE=..`?? So that is something being added by `pg_dump`? In any case, I don't see how you expect to append to a backup file, typically those are binary or special format files and are done (and named with date/time stamps) to make it easy to restore to a specified and know condition as of `$CUR_DATE`. Consider editing your post to show `ls -l backup_db_*` so we can see what is happening. AND don't you want `find ... -name "*.backup_*" ?` Good luck ;-)

Comment: @shellter No that's not something pg_dump ads to it. If i don't use the $CUR_DATE it doesn't create a filename with stars and spaces. And i want to append the .backup extension, not so difficult because you can also define the backupfile as .dump.

If i do ls -l in the corresponding folder it gives me backup_db_01_06_2012??.backup

Comment: consider editing your post with exact copy/paste of the `ls -l *backup*` output. Good luck.

Comment: I ran your script on Mac OS X Lion, just changing some paths to use pg_dump from Postgres 9.1 and it ran just fine. pg_dump did not create a backup file with spaces or asterisks.